# How to use img tag in HTML reader (PHPWord)

Tags: php, image, phpword

I´m using PHPWord to generate the file .docx from html tags.

But img tag in HTML Reader (PHPWord) is unavailable.

Html reader supports these tags:

```
`<p>,<h1>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>,
<strong>,<em>,<sup>,<sub>,
<table>,<tr>,<td>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>.`
```

I specifically want to know if anyone could tell me how to read the img tag with phpword to see images in my .docx

I need to modify this [file](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php) to read img tag.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following:

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addImage(
    'mars.jpg',
    array(
        'width' => 100,
        'height' => 100,
        'marginTop' => -1,
        'marginLeft' => -1,
        'wrappingStyle' => 'behind'
    )
);
```

[See Documentation of PHPWORD](https://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/elements.html#images)

Comment: yes, i can use it, but what i need is read img tag from html. I need to modify  file HTML.php (found in https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php)